# Unable to play video in react native(for android) using youtube video url

Tags: android, reactjs, native

**This is my code below:**

```
<View style={{height:250}}>
    <WebView
       style={ styles.WebViewContainer }
       javaScriptEnabled={true}
       domStorageEnabled={true}
       source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/BE1WzycXP10' }}
     />
</View>
```

When the external player opens and I press the BACK button - application closes without errors. I think that the new intent creates in the same activity.So my question: Is there any way to open video links with external player (like share works but user need to select from video players installed on the system to open shared link with the selected one)

Comment: use https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube

Comment: I think this require youtube API in our app

Comment: I need to play video just from url

Comment: i think Linking.openURL(url) opens youtube player please try